# No se instalo la app debido a un conflicto con un paquete

Tags: apk

hay una aplicación que le modifico el package para poder instalarla más de 1 vez pero hubo una actualización y ahora no me permite, leí  que aparte de modificar el AndroidManifest.xml (package) hay que modificar el build.gradle (applicationId) pero no lo encuentro en la app apk editor pro

Comment: No puedes actualizar una aplicación con una firma distinta a la instalada si te refieres a eso. Si o si tienes que reinstalar.